# The most words that can be made by successively adding one letter to the original word?

Tags: open-ended, letters

What is the largest number of words that can be made by just adding one letter to the original word, where each iteration is a meaningful word? E.g.

```
HO
HON
HONE
HONES
HONEST
HONESTY
```

The original word can have as many letters as you want; you can add letters at the start, at the end or anywhere; and onomatopoeic words are allowed.

Comment: Please also specify the starting state: do you start with a two-letter word?

Comment: Are onomatopoeias allowed?

Comment: letters can be added any way, start with as many letters as you want and onomatopoeias allowed

Comment: please write that detail _into the question_

Comment: _"start with as many letters as you want"_ That doesn't make sense. You could just pick any arbitrary long word and pluralise it. Then the fun part — ensuring that substrings are also words — evaporates!

Comment: Maybe he's looking for the largest difference between starting and ending word lengths. so adding an S to an arbitrarily long word is only worth one point.

Comment: putting this here because it is closely related though obviously completely different questions: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/remove-first-or-last-letter-what-is-the-name-of-this-word-puzzle-type-of-word/1912#1912

Comment: Wow, only at SE would you find that they had already [written a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534087/successive-adding-of-char-to-get-the-longest-word-in-the-dictionary) to do this... No cheating! ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because without defining "word" it turns into an ill-defined, open-ended puzzle (and [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I assume you start at two letters, as in your example. I'm using the circa 2013 *Words With Friends* dictionary.

If you can only add to the right end of the word, **8-letter** words are possible:

```
ba
bar
barb
barbe
barbel
barbell
barbells

ma
max
maxi
maxim
maxima
maximal
maximals

pa
pas
past
paste
paster
pastern
pasterns

re
rep
repo
repos
repose
reposer
reposers
```

If you can add to either end, **9-letter** words are possible:

```
id
aid
aide
aider
aiders
raiders
braiders
abraiders

la
lap
laps
lapse
elapse
relapse
relapser
relapsers

in
pin
ping
aping
raping
craping
scraping
scrapings

at
eat
eath
heath
sheath
sheathe
sheather
sheathers

is
ais
rais
raise
raiser
raisers
praisers
upraisers
```

If you can add at any point, **11-letter** words are possible:

```
pi
pig
ping
oping
coping
comping
compting
competing
completing
complecting
```

Answer (score 10):

To add to Kevin's answer, it's possible to come up with a 11-letter word by adding letters at either end (as illustrated by the answers to [this PPCG question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/45168/3527)):

```
ab
rab
arab
arabi
arabin
arabine
carabine
carabiner
carabinero
carabineros

ra
rah
rahm
brahm
brahma
brahman
brahmani
brahmanis
brahmanism
brahmanisms

ra
ran
fran
franc
franci
francis
francisc
francisca
franciscan
franciscans
```

Answer (score 7):

The longest words in the dictionary that come with my Mac are

> "reversist" and "sheathery", although I can't find a definition for either of them (the earlier stages are all defined in wiktionary, though).

So

> [re](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/re)
>  [rev](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rev)
>  [reve](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reve)
>  [rever](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rever)
>  [revers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/revers)
>  [reversi](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reversi)
>  [reversis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reversis)
>  [reversist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reversist)

or

> [sh](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sh)
>  [she](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/she)
>  [shea](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shea)
>  [sheat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheat)
>  [sheath](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheath)
>  [sheathe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheathe)
>  [sheather](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheather)
>  [sheathery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sheathery)

Comment: A sheathery is a shop that makes sheaths -- that is, a device for holding an edged weapon like a dagger or sword. "Reversist", I have no idea. Seems like a typo for "reservist", frankly. Neither appear to be valid Scrabble words.

Answer (score 2):

The puzzle is to add one letter at a time, ANYWHERE within the word.
Reasonable common words with nine letters would be:
Startling (or starlings)-starling-staring-string-sting-sing-sin-in-I

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> a
> an
> can
> clan
> clean
> cleans
> cleanse
> cleanser
> cleansers
> ```

Comment: Other answers have given longer chains, but thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Starling could be an option.

> ```
> In 
> Sin 
> Sing 
> Sting 
> String
> Staring
> Starling
> Startling
> ```

Comment: Then startling, for nine letters.

Comment: or I
IN
SIN
SING
SINGE
SINGER
SINGERS
STINGERS
STRINGERS

Answer (score 0):

Adding at the end, I give you **contrasters** (11 letters). For 10 letters, I found these:

```
contraster
Romanisers
contrasted 
pastoraled 
pastorales 
minimisers 
quartettes 
quintettes
```

I used [Aspell](http://wordlist.aspell.net/) SCOWL dictionary.

Using a [bigger, lower quality, list](http://www.keithv.com/software/wlist/), I can find *territorialised* and *territorialists* (15), but there are many false positives in that list.

Of course, one can *cheat*. If you start with: *dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane* you can just add an s and put yourself in the nice sum of 32 letters. If we remove chemicals (they can, after all, be arbitrarily long), you have the classic **antidisestablishmentarianism**, that, in its plural form, is 29 letters long.

Comment: I'm confused. What are the letters being added?

Comment: @xnor always at the end.

Comment: Oh, I see, the OP said "start with as many letters as you want", so you're just making a single addition.

Comment: How can there be plural antidisestablishmentarianisms?