# Minimizing Letters

Tags: word, wordplay

The example below shows the amount of letters in the word being minimized by 1 each time, but the letters still form a legitimate word:

[image]

> What is the longest set like this with the initial word longer or equal to 6 letters long?

Comment: This question could be interpreted as a little broad. But also it would require they end with either A or I.

Comment: There are surprisingly many two-letter words in the English language: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/two-letter-words

Comment: [Similar question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/growing-anagrams-what-is-the-longest-possible-list-forming-a-sentence/)

Comment: @SpiritFryer It is a bit different though, not really a duplicate is it?

Comment: @CarlLöndahl Ohhh... I didn't read the last line my bad -_- (Edited to "Similar question")

Comment: OK so aside from the answers from there reversed, how many other ones are there?

Comment: @JoeBeastlyGerbil Is this supposed to be a computer puzzle? It is kind of hard to **prove** that your number of words N is optimal otherwise...

Comment: If you can type up a puzzle that works for this by all means do @CarlLondahl

Comment: Can we settle on a dictionary here? A decent number of the answers include words not in my dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The most words that can be made by successively adding one letter to the original word?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9890/the-most-words-that-can-be-made-by-successively-adding-one-letter-to-the-origina)

Comment: Dictionary.com is a popular choice; however, if you choose a dictionary that can be downloaded as a word list (like [SCOWL](http://wordlist.aspell.net/)), then we can provide an exact answer to the original question ("How many others are there like this?").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it will be very difficult to find a confirmed count of *all* possible words for this. It seems very open-ended. Perhaps it should be switched to a contest to find the longest?

---

<sub>Everything below this is copied from @Kevin from a [very similar question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/9893/9000)</sub>

I'm using the circa 2013 *Words With Friends* dictionary.

If you can only add to the right end of the word, **8-letter** words are possible:

```
a
ba
bar
barb
barbe
barbel
barbell
barbells

a
ma
max
maxi
maxim
maxima
maximal
maximals

a
pa
pas
past
paste
paster
pastern
pasterns
```

If you can add to either end, **9-letter** words are possible:

```
I
id
aid
aide
aider
aiders
raiders
braiders
abraiders

a
la
lap
laps
lapse
elapse
relapse
relapser
relapsers

I
in
pin
ping
aping
raping
craping
scraping
scrapings

a
at
eat
eath
heath
sheath
sheathe
sheather
sheathers

I
is
ais
rais
raise
raiser
raisers
praisers
upraisers
```

If you can add at any point, **11-letter** words are possible:

```
I   
pi
pig
ping
oping
coping
comping
compting
competing
completing
complecting
```

Comment: Nice idea about the competition, I'll change the question

Comment: The "at any point" 11-letter answer fits the criteria (note the example removes R from the middle)

Answer (score 4):

Using *Mathematica*'s dictionary, my longest chain is:

### 10 Letters:

> `SPLITTINGS`, `SPLITTING`, `SLITTING`, `SITTING`, `SITING`, `STING`, `SING`, `SIN`, `IN`, `I`

My code is below, it takes less than a second to run.

```
words = ToUpperCase @ DictionaryLookup[___];

g = Graph[Join @@ Table[StringDrop[w, {#}] -> w & /@ Range[StringLength[w]], {w, words}]];

reachable = VertexOutComponent[g, {""}];

MaximalBy[reachable, StringLength]

FindShortestPath[g, "", First @ %]
```

The strategy is to create a tree-like structure were each word is linked to all the "words" that can be created by dropping one letter.  Some of those words are not in the dictionary (psuedo-words), but they can be ignored since there is no path to them from the root node (the empty word).

Once this structure is created, finding the solution is simple: find the longest word that can be reached from the root node.

## How  many?

To answer your original question (how many chains are there), we can try counting the number of reachable words of each length:

```
Grid[List @@@ Normal@GroupBy[reachable, StringLength, Length]]

0   1
1   2
2   29
3   254
4   942
5   1561
6   1390
7   878
8   325
9   51
10  1
```

A total of `2645` words at least six letters long can be put into a chain.  This doesn't exactly answer your question however, since some words can be reached in multiple ways:

```
AcyclicGraphQ[UndirectedGraph@g] (* False *)
```

In order to find the total number of ways to make each word, I make use of a recursive enumeration:

> The number of ways to make a word is equal to the sum of the number of ways to make each of its predecessors.

From here we can make use of the *adjacency matrix* of our graph.  The adjacency matrix $A$ has entries $a_{ij}$ equal to the number of edges from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.  If the number of ways to make the word (vertex) $i$ is $c_i$, then we can write:

$$
  c_i = \sum_j c_j a_{ji}
$$

Notice this is exactly equal to the matrix multiplication $c=A^{\intercal} c$, making finding $c$ equivalent to finding the eigenvector of $A^{\intercal}$.  (There is one complication: we have to set $a_{11}=1$, otherwise the number of ways to reach the empty word `""` is zero.)

```
clean = Subgraph[g, reachable]; (* remove unreachable words *)
m = AdjacencyMatrix[clean];
m[[1, 1]] = 1;
e = First@Eigenvectors[N@Transpose@m, 1];
Total[Pick[Round[e/First[e]], VertexList[clean], x_ /; StringLength[x] >= 6]]
```

giving an answer of `26,322` (for *Mathematica*'s word list).  This solution is very fast, even on much larger word lists (~100,000 words).

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused as to whether the question is "How many six-letter words can you find that fit this pattern?" or "What is the longest word you can create that fits this pattern?" I will answer the latter.

### Longest word: 9 letters

> CLEANSERS
> CLEANSES
> CLEANSE
> CLEANS
> CLEAN
> LEAN
> LEA
> LA
> A

Answer (score 2):

Without  resorting to (read as: figuring out)  a program to determine all the possible and best answers, here is what I've come up with for words **longer** than six letters:

amasses masses masse mass ass as a *(though the E should have an accent in masse...)*

> mangled mangle mange mane man an a
> sharped shared shard hard had ad a

EIGHT!

> prattled rattled ratted rated rate rat at a
> startled started stated state stat tat at a

Forget EIGHT, move on to NINE!

> spiriting spirting spiting siting sting sing sin in i
>  *(spirting is antiquated, so 8 and 9 could be splitting and spitting)*

Answer (score 1):

I have one that's six (or seven if you count proper nouns)

> I
>   IN
>   SIN
>   SINE
>   SPINES
>   SPLINES
>   SPLINERS - questionable, it's a company name

edit: improvement

> I
>   IN
>   PIN
>   PINE
>   PINED
>   SPINED
>   SPLINED

edit: and one starting with O

> O
>   ON
>   TON
>   TONE
>   TONER
>   STONER
>   STONIER

Answer (score 1):

> SKATERS
>    SKATER
>    SKATE
>    SATE
>    ATE
>    AT
>    A

and...

> STRAINS
> TRAINS
> TRAIN
> RAIN
> RAN
> AN
> A

Another!

> BRAINED
> BRINED
> BRINE
>  [BINE](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bine)
> BIN
> IN
> I

I'll keep thinking on this one...