# What word is still a word, when you take a letter away

Tags: riddle

> I have a word in mind.
>
> This word is eight letters long.
>
> If you wisely choose a letter and take it away, you get a new word
>   with different meaning.
>
> If you repeat this, you get another new word.
>
> At the end, there is one letter left.

What word do I have in mind?

Comment: There is a famous riddle [like this](https://www.riddles.com/2316).

Answer (score 4):

Well I guess the answer is:

> Starting

This word is eight letters long.

> Starting

If you wisely choose a letter and take it away, you get a new word with different meaning.

> Staring after removing t

If you repeat this, you get another new word.

> String, Sting , Sing , Sin , in

At the end, there is one letter left.

> I

Answer (score 1):

There is a popular example of even a 9-letter word:

> STARTLING
>
>  remove the L, and the word becomes: STARTING
>
>  remove one T, and the word becomes: STARING
>
>  remove the A, and the word becomes: STRING
>
>  remove the R, and the word becomes: STING
>
>  remove the other T, and the word becomes: SING
>
>  remove the G, and the word becomes: SIN
>
>  remove the S, and the word becomes: IN
>
>  remove the N, and the word becomes: I
>
>  and because the author asked for 8-letter word, just start from the second line, i.e. STARTING

Comment: I'm searching the dup...

Comment: The author says that it is an 8-letter word, not a 9-letter word.

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9890/the-most-words-that-can-be-made-by-successively-adding-one-letter-to-the-origina (I failed my flagging, can't flag dup anymore)

Comment: @Saeïdryl More similar words in https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6691/growing-anagrams-what-is-the-longest-possible-list-forming-a-sentence/6696#6696

Comment: @u_ndefined Just skip the first line then.