# A word if you take one letter away at a time you will be left with a two letter word

Tags: riddle, word, no-computers

> A word where if you take away one letter away at a time you end up
>   with a two letter word.

What is it?

**Hint 1**:

> It is an 8 letter word

**Hint 2**:

> The final word left is *in*

The word is not mentioned in [The most words that can be made by successively adding one letter to the original word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9890).

Comment: @D Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I doubt if this is too broad. Please be noted that excessively broad questions may face the crisis of being closed. Happy Puzzling!

Comment: Welcome!  Do you mean to say that you get a new word each time you remove a letter?  Otherwise many words would qualify as long as they have a two letter word inside them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suggest a word not found in the dupe,

> [Starling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eakKfY5aHmY)

can be decomposed as

> ```
>  STARLING
>  STAR ING
>  ST R ING
>  ST   ING
>  S    ING
>  S    IN
>       IN
> ```